# How to add eclipse data management in mac os

Tags: java, eclipse

In my eclipse application preferences  has not include Data Management tab.How can I add Data Management to the preferences

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I installed postgresql on my laptop. Then I want to add it  eclipse libraries for using them with all projects.To add it , I must see Data Manager item in eclipse preferences menu. But it doesn't seen in the preferences menu. How can I add Data Management to the eclipse preferences menu? Or has it a different way  to add database to all projects for Mac os eclipse?